# Finding all strings of a specific length using re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all strings of a certain length from a text using a regular expression, more precisely with this instruction :

`words=re.findall('\w{3}',text)`

Here I get all strings of length 3, however I want to make it more general and have the possibility to put another number as an input instead of the '3', so I would have something like this :

```
order = 5 #for example
words = re.findall('\w{order}',text)
```

This instruction doesn't work in my case but I just wanted to illustrate my problem.

Any ideas ? Thank you for your help

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w{{{}}}'.format(order), text)` (or `r'\w{%s}'%order`)

Comment: @Rawing should be `r"\w{{{}}}".format(order)`.

Comment: @kennytm Good call, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To *extract all strings of a certain length from a text* use word boundary anchor `\b` in regex expression:

```
text = ' ... another number as an input instead of the 3, so I would have something like this '
order = 5 #for example
words = re.findall(r'\b\w{{{}}}\b'.format(order), text)
print(words)
```

The output:

```
['input', 'would']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are all of the methods of doing this:

Method 1:

```
re.findall(r'\w{%s}' % (order), text)
```

Method 2:

```
re.findall(r'\w{'+str(order)+'}', text)
```

Method 3:

```
re.findall(r'\w{{{}}}'.format(order), text)
```